# Simple image gallery, new to jquery and looking for guidance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so I have the following: http://prntscr.com/b71b2e
I am looking for the smaller boxes to contain images and the larger box to contain the selected image by default but to be switched to others when selected.
I am new to jquery and I think this would be a novice level thing to do so could someone explain to me what I'd have to do?

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```
.photos {
    width:1000px;
    height:1000px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    padding:0px;    
}

.main-photo {
    width:988px;
    height:550px;
    margin-left:5px;
    border: thin solid #666;
    margin-bottom:20px; 
}

.main-photo-text {
    margin-top:500px;
    height:50px;
    width:auto;
    float:left; 
    font-size:200%;
    color:#FFF;
    text-shadow: #000 2px 2px;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

///

```
<div class="photos">

<div class="main-photo">
    <div class="main-photo-text">Project Name</div>
</div>

<a class="photo" href="#"></a>
<a class="photo" href="#"></a>
<a class="photo" href="#"></a>
<a class="photo" href="#"></a>
<a class="photo" href="#"></a>
<a class="photo" href="#"></a>
<a class="photo" href="#"></a>
<a class="photo" href="#"></a>
<a class="photo" href="#"></a>
<a class="photo" href="#"></a>


</div>
```

Comment: There are 100's of plugins and tutorials on this. Question is simply too broad for this site

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to make this, you can use `data-` to accomplish this, make two containers, one for main photos and another for small photos , then put your big images in the main photo container and give to them a data name related to them such `data-target=img1` 2 3 ..., and give to small photos data name such `data-status=img1` 2 3 etc.... and put them in a div not in anchor.

then make the big images disappearing by giving `display:none`/ `visibility:hidden` or `opacity:0` to them except the first image as it will be visible as a default or by fade them out using JQ on page load.

In JQuery the main base which you will build your function on it is when some one click on small image such `data-status="img1"` it will show the div with `data-target` name equal to it `data-target="img1"` and same for the rest, then you can do this https://jsfiddle.net/v7yf880a/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('div[data-status]').on('click', function () {
    var thsData = $(this).data('status');
    $('div[data-target]').fadeOut(0);
    $('div[data-target="' + thsData + '"]').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.photos {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.target {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  position: relative
}

.target div[data-target] {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/600x300);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.target div[data-target]:not(:nth-of-type(1)) {
  display: none;
}

.status {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  float: left
}

.status div[data-status] {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #9b59b6;
  margin: 4px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="photos">

  <div class="target">
      <div data-target="img1">Project Name1</div>
      <div data-target="img2">Project Name2</div>
      <div data-target="img3">Project Name3</div>
      <div data-target="img4">Project Name4</div>
      <div data-target="img5">Project Name5</div>
      <div data-target="img6">Project Name6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="status">
    <div data-status="img1">Project Name</div>
    <div data-status="img2">Project Name</div>
    <div data-status="img3">Project Name</div>
    <div data-status="img4">Project Name</div>
    <div data-status="img5">Project Name</div>
    <div data-status="img6">Project Name</div>
  </div>

</div>
```